# Visual Studio 2017 entity framework designer disabling auto-commit

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2014

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to create an Entity Framework for my database in Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
I created many stored producer to manipulate that database tables and add those procedure to my Entity Framework designer.
So, Is there any way to call stored procedures to manipulate the data without auto-commit ?

Comment: Why do you want that? It sounds like you should use a development database and not code against production. Or use an in-memory database for unit tests. Explain your scenario.

Comment: I am generated the entity using wizard in Visual Studio 2017. I am not writing any code. And I called several database stored procedure in a page. So, I don't need a procedure to execute if any other procedure fire an error.

Comment: My question is: why do you want to call a stored procedure through Entity Framework without actually hitting the database?

Comment: I just want to auto generate the code that call the procedure without coding it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by:
1. disable auto-commit from SQL Server.
2. Begin a transaction in the database transaction scope from C# code behind and use transaction.Commit() if the scope successes and transaction.Rollback() if any exception appears.